# Parse keys from string

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

how can I parse keys from string?

```js
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');
...
const obj = {val: 'Key.SPACE'}
if(obj.val.startsWith('Key.'))obj.val = eval(obj.val);
(...).sendKeys(obj.val);
```

Now the code works like this, but I would like to remove the `eval`

Comment: I don't believe in this particular example you can avoid using eval, because `Key` is a constant and constants and local variables are not stored like global variables in an scope object.

Comment: @vanowm `if('Key.SPACE')return Key.SPACE` 

Comment: it will be the same exact result with: `if('whateveryouwanthere')return Key.SPACE` You are checking if a string empty or not

Comment: Now, if you'd have  something like `const myObj = require('selenium-webdriver');` than it would be pretty easy do without `eval()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the "property name" substring after the dot (in this case, 'SPACE'). Then use that as a property name in the Key object, using [] notation rather than '.':

```
obj.val = Key[ property_name_string_eg_SPACE ];
```

Comment: I haven't touched this option for so long, and forgot about it, hah